# How to combine project yml configurations for Quarkus in profile.yml

Tags: java, quarkus, configuration-files

We've used [quarkus](https://quarkus.io/get-started/) as basement for new project services.
Considering its configuration, it can be configured using `yml` files.

To follow [this](https://quarkus.io/guides/config-yaml) way, added

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-config-yaml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

`yml` configuration applied. To improve this configuration, I'd like to have a chance put some configurations in different files and combine them together, depending on...

For example I need next configurations in separate files:

- `application-postgre-ds.yml`
- `application-oracle-ds.yml`
- `application-xxx-ds.yml`
- ...
- `application-apigee.yml`

I'd like to manage them in my main `profile` configuration like other profiles imports

```
quarkus:
  profiles:
    include: postgre-ds, oracle-ds
```

or like imports from classpath

```
quarkus:
  import:
    config: classpath:application-postgre-ds.yml;application-oracle-ds.yml
```

but haven't detected nothing useful in their documentation.

I hope I missed correct instruction and someone would help me make working combined configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is partially supported by Quarkus:

It is possible to have specific configurations files per profile:
https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#profile-aware-files

But in Quarkus, you can only have a single profile active. For instance, if the profile `dev` is active, Quarkus will load configurations both from `application-dev.properties` and the main file `application.properties`. Configuration from the profile-aware file has priority.

There is also the notion of a parent profile, which you can use to share common configuration across multiple profiles: https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#parent-profile

If you really need the multi-profile approach, as I said, Quarkus does not officially support it, but it is supported by SmallRye Config (used by Quarkus): https://smallrye.io/smallrye-config/latest/config/profiles/#multiple-profiles. It should work for this use case, but it is not integrated into Quarkus, so some Quarkus features around configuration profiles will not work properly. For instance, the `@IfBuildProfile` and `@UnlessBuildProfile` annotations, but there are more cases. So use it carefully.